Boolean valued functions that act on infinite binary sequences
Recently, based on my recent work on truth tables and a cute trick I discovered to literally write truth tables as non-negative integers in base 2 in their natural order, I asked myself the following question:
(1) "is it possible to obtain a complete classification of all possible boolean valued functions which act on infinite binary sequences, as is possible in the finite case; and if not, what is the best we can do?"
If we imagine an infinite binary sequences as a repeating binary decimal expansion, I think a good way to think about what's going on here is: we are really asking for a classification of boolean valued functions $\phi$ which act on the open interval $(0,1)$ of the real line.
$$\phi : (0,1) \to \{0,1\}$$
There is a really nice symmetry in the notation I used above, which makes me wonder if there is something going on here that might be very interesting.
Any insights or references would be much appreciated, and I'm wondering if anyone has a possible suggestion about how to go about obtaining an answer to my question (1).

Shouldn't your $\phi$ act on the closed interval? Otherwise what real number corresponds to the sequence that is all zeros, or all ones?

You are talking about countable infinity, are you?

@MartianInvader great question!  first of all, the reason for choosing an open interval is to create a situation where everything im working with is an open set, and trying to use ideas from topology.  There is a subtle issue related to your question, consider that 0.0111.. = 0.1000... this means our measure is not always unique which is weird.  There are only 2 possible boolean valued functions acting on either .000.. or .111... so its not a problem to use closed intervals for obtaining a complete classification from that perspective.  does that answer your question?

@GyroGearloose can you please rephrase your comment and clarify what you are referring to when about "countable infinity"?  I don't understand the question.

I down-voted because your question lacks clarity. Of course you can classify those functions, but it is utterly unclear in what way you want to do this.

@GyroGearloose ah I understand, no worries.  My idea is that by writing the truth tables as non negative integers in base 2, its easy to obtain a complete classification of all possible boolean valued functions that act on finite binary sequences.  For 2 boolean input variables there are 4 possible input combinations: 00, 01, 10, 11, and 16 possible truth tables 0000, 0001, ... ,111.  This is a complete classification and shows there are 16 binary boolean operators.  By taking the limit we land in the space of infinite binary sequences (cont...)

You said "can you please rephrase your comment and clarify what you are referring to when about "countable infinity"? I don't understand the question." and I say, if you don't know about countable infinity, you are either an AI-bot or lack effort for the question.

(...cont) I absolutely want to encourage you to feel free to downvote so the site is properly curated and maximizes the helpfulness of the large dataset for others.  I am always trying to improve the quality of my questions by taking constructive feedback like yours very seriously.  Recently my questions have been getting closed for providing too much extra info like the cute trick I just explained to write truth tables in their natural order and treat them like non negative integers.  Hope that clears it up!

@GyroGearloose I am deeply honored by your comment where you speculate if I am an AI.  I promise you I am a real person lol to be clear, you asked me if i was talking about countable infinity without providing enough context about what part of my question you were referring to.  your comment is extremely unclear for this reason.

@GyroGearloose I apologize for the confusion, and believe I understand your original comment now.  The answer is: yes, I am thinking about covering (0,1) with a countable collection of open intervals for the purpose of obtaining the classification for my question (1), not an uncountable number of open intervals

I'll take a stab at this. One possible answer is:
Yes, boolean functions on $(0,1)$ correspond to subsets of $(0,1)$. We can simply identify a function $\phi: (0,1) \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ with the set $\{x \in (0,1) | \phi(x) =  1\}$.
If you find this unsatsifying, you may want to know "Is there a complete classification of subsets of $(0,1)$?"
In this case I'd say the answer is No. There are many ways to classify subsets of real numbers from different areas of mathematics:

By cardinality: Finite, countable, and uncountable sets
Topologically: Open, closed, cardinality of connected components, homeomorphism type, etc.
Algebraically: Sets that are closed under some operation or operations (such as subgroups of the group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and their cosets).
Measure theoretically: Under a given measure, measurable vs. non-measurable, and among measurable sets you can classify by what their measure is.
Order theoretically: Order isomorphism type.

All of these have their uses, but none of them really classify sets "completely" in a way that is useful for all applications. Indeed, if such sets were trivializable, it seems unlikely that $\mathbb{R}$ would have the status it does as one of the most fundamentally important objects in mathematics.

great answer, thanks.  I will wait until more people have had a chance to answer, and am planning to accept this answer at that time, if its the best of the available options.

im wondering if you would you agree with the following assertion, why or why not: “the boolean valued functions that act on infinite binary sequences and which represent decidable yes/no questions, correspond to computable subsets of (0,1)” (here by computable subsets of (0,1) I am referring to subsets which can be defined by an algorithm).

@MattCalhoun You have to be very, very careful how you define a "subset which can be defined by an algorithm". You can't input an arbitrary real number to an algorithm (since real numbers cannot be specified with a finite amount of data), and if you try to write an algorithm that somehow enumerates the elements of the set then you can only have countable sets. I suspect that the truth of your statement will become clear if you can provide a more rigorous definition.

I have worked out a prototype way to define computable subset, and have a specific algorithm in mind which is modeled on the case of truth tables which act on finite binary sequences.  Instead of posting it here as a comment (its way too long for that) I will attempt to make this as rigorous as possible and if I get stuck will post a follow up question.

A classification of boolean-valued functions $\phi:(0,1)\to \{0,1\}$ is essentially a classification of subsets $\phi^{-1}(1)$ of $(0,1)$. As was already noted in MartianInvader's answer,
there are many classifications provided for different purposes.
But since each set which we describe is described by a finitely many symbols, we can grasp at most countable many subsets of $(0,1)$. But there is a wild horde, $2^{\frak c}$ many, of them. Even the sizes of horde members are problematic. For instance, is there a set whose size is strictly between the cardinalities $\omega$ of natural numbers and $\frak c$ of the real numbers? The answer to this question is independent of the ZFC, the Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (with the axiom of choice)! Also I expect that the smallest size of a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set or of a nonmeager set also depend on axioms additional to ZFC,
but I failed to find a reference to the exact claim now.
On the other hand, descriptive set theory provides
rather naturals ways to describe sets according to the complexity of their construction.

I'd like to mention, I believe (conjecture) the answer to my question (1) is: no, no such classification can exist; the boolean functions which cannot be classified correspond to undecidable yes/no questions; and the infinite binary sequences which represent undecidable yes/no questions are mapped to dyadic rational numbers in (0,1), and its possible to use limit operations to refine and shrink the set of binary sequences which represent undecidable questions, until arriving at a complete classification of all possible decidable yes/no questions.

ultimately, if a yes/no question is decidable, this means its possible to write an algorithm to make that decision, therefore what we are really talking about by "decidable" is another way of saying "computable" boolean valued functions.  Thanks for your great answer, it contains a number of observations from perspectives I had not previously fully considered.
